# How come Arc<Mutex> has a lock method but Arc<i32> does not in Rust?

Tags: rust

Just playing around with Arc and Mutex and I discover that the `join` method only shows up on value of type `Arc<Mutex<i32>>` but not when `Arc<i32>` is used directly.

```
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    counter.lock() // method exists and returns LockResult<MutexGuard<'_, T>>

    // but
    let counter = Arc::new(0);
    counter.lock() // method does not exist
```

I would have thought `lock` is a method on `Arc` given the first example, but it seems that method only appears when `Arc` wraps a `Mutex`

What type machinery allows this to happen?

Comment: Becuase `Mutex` has a `lock` method and `i32` doesn't. `Arc` [derefs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) to its pointee, letting you call its methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `lock()` method belongs to `Mutex`. However, the `Arc` is a smart pointer type. Due to Rust's [deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#more-on-deref-coercion), it automatically "forwards" methods not present on the smart pointer type (here `Arc`) to the underlying type (here `Mutex`).

I recommend reading the chapter [Treating Smart Pointers Like Regular References with the Deref Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-02-deref.html#treating-smart-pointers-like-regular-references-with-the-deref-trait) from the Rust Book.